# Are C header files included in the Linux kernel and maintained by them?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

Looking at the Linux system calls on this page:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_2.html

Most of the sys calls have a `libc wrapper` function available for use.
Lets look at `gettid` as an example:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html

```c
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t gettid(void);
```

My questions are:

- Is `<unistd.h>` provided and maintained by the Linux kernel itself or `libc` or some other project? Are these the same as `kernel headers`?
- If it is provided by Linux itself then why won't they provide the definition as well, why just provide the function prototype and leave the implementation for other libraries like `libc`?
- If not provided by Linux itself then why bother putting the function prototype here at all? `libc` should be able to implement it however it wants.

Comment: Note that to use the actual syscalls, you could use the [`syscall` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html). And `unistd.h` is part of the POSIX standard, and any OS using the Linux kernel is likely to be POSIX compliant.

Comment: The Unix API, as documented by the man pages, is defined for most programmers at the level of C, and so it's a sort of cooperative endeavor between the kernel and the C library.  Neither one can just go off in its own direction without breaking everything.

Answer (score 0):

> Is `<unistd.h>` provided and maintained by the Linux kernel itself or `libc` or some other project? Are these the same as `kernel headers`?

No, the `unistd.h` file that gets used when you `#include <unistd.h>` isn't from the Linux kernel (even though it does have some files with that name). It comes from your libc, probably `glibc`: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=include/unistd.h;hb=HEAD.

> If not provided by Linux itself then why bother putting the function prototype here at all? libc should be able to implement it however it wants.

Convention is that the libc wrappers for syscalls should mirror the name and arguments of the syscall itself, so there really isn't room for deviation between libc's.